# How to start a Docker container with cloud-config file for CoreOS?

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker, coreos

I'm trying to configure my CoreOS server with Terraform, using [cloud-config file for  CoreOS](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/cloud-config.html). I am currently trying to set up a Mongo database in a *Docker* container.
Here is my config file:

```
write_files:
  - path: "/home/core/keyfile"
  permissions: "0600"
  owner: "999"
  content: |
    hUoQVrERB0*** <here is my key for MongoDB>

coreos:
  units:
    - name: "dockerstart.service"
      command: "start"
      content: |
        [Unit]
        Description=Start
        Author=Me

        [Service]
        Restart=always
        ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --name mongo -v /home/core:/opt --add-host node1.example.com:127.0.0.1 -p 27017:27017 -d mongo:2.6.5 --smallfiles --keyFile /opt/keyfile --replSet "rs0"
        ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker rm -f mongo
```

I am not sure how to use coreOS `units` (when I ssh into the server, the docker container is not running, so the config file is not correct). According to [CoreOS Validator](https://coreos.com/validate/), my file is valid. Also, I am not sure if that is the simplest way to deploy a MongoDB server.
**How to properly use CoreOS `units` ? Any thoughts on a way to improve how deploy a Mongo Database ?**

Any help, comments, suggestions are appreciated !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found the solution.

Actually running `docker run` with `-d` option daemonizes the command. So, when `systemd` founds out that this action runs in the background, it considers that Docker is crashing.

Here is `journalctl -u dockerstart.service` result on server :

```
docker[1237]: ace3978442a729420ecb87af224bd146ec6ac7912c5cc452570735f4a3be3a79
docker[1297]: mongo
systemd[1]: dockerstart.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped Start.
systemd[1]: Started Start.
```

Here you can clearly see that `systemd` stops and restarts the `Start` service.

So the solution for this might be **removing -d from the `docker run` command**.

Answer (score 0):

If help you in the future, you can use a Container Linux Config file format for setup the initial config for CoreOS:
I published an example that create an ignition config based on a Container Linux Config file applied to Terraform in: https://github.com/joariasl/terraform-ansible-docker-swarm-coreos-aws/tree/feature/coreos-etcd

About this: https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/provisioning.html